# If $x$ and $y$ are $M$-regular, then $xy$ is $M$-regular.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $M$ be an $R$-module.

Recall that $x$ is a non-zero divisor on $M$ if $x\cdot m = 0$ if and only if $m=0$.

Recall that a sequence $x_1,\dots, x_n$ of elements of $R$ is a weakly $M$-regular sequence if $x_1$ is a non-zero divisor on $M$, and $x_2$ is a non-zero divisor on $M/x_1M$ and $x_i$ is a non-zero divison on $M/(x_1,\dots, x_{i-1})M$.

Recall that a weakly $M$-regular sequence $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is an $M$-regular sequence if $M/(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)M\ne 0$.

One can show that if $0\to U\to M\to N\to 0$ is an exact sequence of $R$-modules, and $\underline{x}$ is weakly $U$-regular, and (weakly) $N$-regular. Then $\underline{x}$ is (weakly) $M$-regular.

There is an exercise to show that if $x$ and $y$ are both (weakly) $M$-regular, then $xy$ is (weakly) $M$-regular. The weak part of this is obvious. So it remains to show that $M/xM\not\cong 0\not\cong M/yM$ then $M/xyM\not\cong 0$. They give the hint to use that fact about exact sequences I write above, where they suggest finding an exact sequence with $M/xyM$ in the middle.

But isn't it obvious immediately that for any $R$-module at all $M$ and $x\in R$ that $xM\subseteq M$, and so $xyM\subseteq xM\subseteq M$, and where $M/xyM\cong 0 \implies xyM = M$ and hence would imply $xM=M$, which would be a contradiction?

Comment: Your reasoning seems right to me. Could it be that the hint is for a different part of the problem?